# Start, stop, cancel, edit workflow for ag-grid with server-side data and custom REST API

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I would like to setup an editing experience with the following requirements using ag-grid.

1. Fetching data using a ServerSideDatasource
2. In a toolbar above the data grid have a button to

   - start an edit session (cannot edit outside of an edit session)
   - cancel and edit session (discard edits and don’t save anything to the server)
   - stop/save and edit session (save edits to server)
3. Enabled the ag-grid undo/redo capabilities
4. I have a REST API used for CRUD operations on the server-side data

I am using the term “edit session” to describe when the data can be changed. This is, as far as I know, not a concept provided by ag-grid and would be managed by our application.
The workflow would be the following. If the user double clicks any cell in the data grid, and the edit session has not started, they should be prevented from changing any data. The data grid should be read only. To edit any data the user will first have to click the start editing button which will begin the edit session. Now if the user double clicks any cell in any row they should be able to change the data. They should also be able to perform undo and redo operations (i.e., ctrl + Z to undo) during the edit session.

When they have finished editing cells they have two options. They can click the stop/save button which will end the edit session and use our REST API to update the data on the server. The other option would be they can click the cancel button which will discard any edits made to the table and revert back to the state the table was in before they stated editing. In this case there is no need to call the server (unless I need to re-fetch the data to reload the table but I would hope to not have to do that).

I have been able to achieve part of this workflow by setting editable to true for all of my column defs, disabled click to edit by using  suppressClickEdit, and from the cellDoubleClicked event I check my own isEditing Boolean and if true call startEditingCell().
I was hoping that the grid would keep track of all the cells that have changed and provide an array of changes (taking into account the undo/redo) like a transaction that I could translate into the payload necessary to call our REST API to apply the changes to the server. If the user cancels the edit session I was also hoping the grid would let me revert its state back to before the edit session started.

I have revied the different options for SSRM updating but those options do not seem to apply to this workflow.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-updating

The read-only-edit looks promising but I am not sure where to store all the old values and new values so that the user can cancel the edit session and discard all edits.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-setters/#read-only-edit

I do not mind using NgRX to manage the state but I am not sure how to move forward. If anyone could offer any suggestions as to which parts of the ag-gird API to leverage, please let me know.

Thanks